# Perspective warp using opencv and displaying it using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to apply a perspective warp to a video using opencv and then displaying it using a label in tkinter. However when the code is run the video imports however it does not displayed the window just closes and no error messages are given.

```
def perspective():
   file = askopenfilename()
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
   def main():
       ret, img1 = cap.read()
       img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
       rows, columns, channels = img1.shape
       point1 = np.float32([[200, 200], [440, 200], [0, 360], [640, 360]])
       point2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [640, 0], [0, 360], [640, 360]])
       P = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(point1, point2)
       output = cv2.warpPerspective(img1, P, (640, 360))
       img = Image.fromarray(output)
       imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
       vid_original = Label(root)
       vid_original.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(150, 20), pady=2)
       vid_original.imgtk = imgtk
       vid_original.configure(image=imgtk)
       vid_original.after(10, main)
   main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
perspective()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tk, as any GUI, needs to run a message loop.

please find and follow Tk/tkinter tutorials that show you the basics.

alternatively, don't use tkinter, but use `cv2.imshow` and `cv2.waitKey` (which spins the message loop).